# Error launching Android Studio: path error for JAVA_HOME

Tags: android-studio

```
---------------------------
Error launching Android Studio
---------------------------
The environment variable JAVA_HOME (with the value of 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin;) 
does not point to a valid JVM installation.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Sorry, but, where JAVA_HOME must point to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/index.html
It should point to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05